# Resources warning

Tags: resources, uwp

I'm seeing a warning in my uwp project:

```
Warning     Resources found for language(s) 'en' but no resources found for default language(s): 'en-US'. Change the default language or qualify resources with the default language. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=231899 Jockusch.Calculator.WindowsStore    C:\Users\William\Documents\calculator\Jockusch.Calculator.WindowsStore\MakePRI
```

Is there a way to tell what resources, precisely, the warning is referring to? I tried deleting my whole "Resources" folder. This had no effect. I also tried changing the default language in my Package.appxmanifest file from 'en-US' to 'en'. Amazingly, that also had no effect -- the warning still appeared and said the default language was 'en-US'.

Comment: Can you provided a complete repro? Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: VS version:  Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586

Comment: Complete repro -- probably not. That's kinda the issue. I have no idea what resource file it is complaining about, or how to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback. This is a known issue in VS/MSBuild. We are syncing with the related team on this issue. The warning is coming from the fact that .NET Core Framework binaries have "en-US" as a default language. Temporarily, the only possible workaround is to declare default language "en-US". However, this warning should not break your dev progress, you can ignore it and move forward. ;)